# Should Whatif and ConfirmImpact have an else clause?

Tags: powershell, confirm

I want to include `Whatif` and `Confirm` to my functions but I encountered an issue with these parameters.
My functions are structured like this:

```
function Get-Stuff {
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact='High')]
  param ( {...} )
  process {
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Name, "Delete user")) {
      $result = Invoke-RestMethod @restBody            
    }
  }
  end {
    Write-Output -InputObject $result
    Remove-Variable -Name result
  }
}
```

I took on a habit to clean up my variables in the end-block with `Remove-Variable`. When I use now the `-WhatIf` or the `-Confirm` parameter (and denying it), I get an error that the `$result` variable is null.

```
ErrorRecord                 : Cannot find a variable with the name 'result'.
```

I understand that the RestMethod is skipped in this case but I would assume that the rest of the function would not be executed further.

My question is now, does one add an else-clause to end the continuing execution of the function or do I use these parameters incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's no good reason to remove your variables in the `end` block**, since they go out of scope automatically anyway, given that they're local to your function.

(The only thing that makes sense is to `.Dispose()` of variables containing objects that implement the [`System.IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IDisposable) interface; if releasing memory as quickly as possible is paramount - at the expense of blocking execution temporarily - you can additionally call `[GC]::Collect(); [GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`)

**If you still want to call [`Remove-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/remove-variable)**, you have two options:

- Simply *ignore* a non-existent variable by adding `-ErrorAction Ignore` to the `Remove-Variable` call.

  ```
  Remove-Variable -Name result -ErrorAction Ignore
  ```
- Alternatively, protect the call - and the `Write-Output` object - with an explicit test for the existence of the variable:

  ```
  if (Get-Variable -Scope Local result -ErrorAction Ignore) {
    $result # short for: Write-Output -InputObject 
    Remove-Variable -Name result
  }
  ```

Also note that **it's typical for output objects to be emitted directly from the `process` block** - emitting from the `end` block is only a necessity for commands that for conceptual reasons must collect all input first, such as [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object).

**Emitting output objects from the `process` block - which is invoked *for each input object* - ensures the *streaming output behavior*** - emitting objects *one by one*, as soon as they're available - that the pipeline was designed for.